# jquery hover/mouseover bug

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, mouseout

Iam trying to display a tooltip when mouseovering and hide it when mouseout.

I used :

```
var keepTab = false;
            var sC = $('#SwitchContent')
             $('#navbar img').mouseenter(function(){
                sC.show("slow");
                LoadPage($(this).attr('alt'));
                keepTab = false;
                sC.removeClass("selected");
            }).mouseout(function(){
                if (!keepTab){
                    sC.fadeOut("slow");
                }
            });

            $('#navbar img').click(function(){
                keepTab = true;
                sC.addClass("selected");
            });
```

and the html

```
<div id="navbar" style="margin-top: <?= $navBar_margintop ?>px">
  <img src="images/tab9.gif" alt="tab9" style="margin-right: <?= $margintab9 ?>px" height="<?= $navbarH[8] ?>" width="<?= $navbarW[8] ?>"/>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <img src="images/tab1.gif" alt="tab1" style="margin-right: <?= $margintab1 ?>px" height="<?= $navbarH[0] ?>" width="<?= $navbarW[0] ?>"/>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  <img src="images/tab2.gif" alt="tab2" style="margin-right: <?= $margintab2 ?>px" height="<?= $navbarH[1] ?>" width="<?= $navbarW[1] ?>"/>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  ....
  <img src="images/tab8.gif" alt="tab8" style="margin-right: <?= $margintab8 ?>px" height="<?= $navbarH[7] ?>" width="<?= $navbarW[7] ?>"/>
```

I also tried hover. but they both had a bug where the show and hide actions gets stuck in a loop (only part of the time). This happens in all of the browsers.

A live example can be viewed  [here](http://www.s-maof.com/LandingPages/PRO/)

thanks.

edit:

also tried mouseenter..

Comment: Try using `.mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`.

Comment: Can you include your HTML please and definitions for sC and keepTab?

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle.net example? so we can fiddle around to fix your issue..

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I'm thinking the animations are actually what you think is the "loop" if you run your mouse over all of the images than it has to queue all the animations and run through them until it gets to the one you want... Just a thought

Comment: check out this and see if that helps you at all http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/3ppr8/23/